# Only first word of a sentence seen in Java

Tags: java, string, char, if-statement

I'm a newbie writing Java code.  I haven't read about loops yet.  I'm just up to if-else statements.  My code works except when I enter a sentence only the first word is recognized.  If I enter a sentence with no spaces it works perfectly.  How can I get the code to see the whole sentence?  Thanks!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Program04
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Write a complete sentence with proper grammer:");
        String sentence = keyboard.next();
        boolean qMark = sentence.contains("?");
        boolean wow = sentence.contains("!");
        if (qMark)
            System.out.println("Yes");
        else if (wow)
            System.out.println("Wow");
        else
            System.out.println("You always say that.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
keyboard.nextLine();
```

instead of

```
keyboard.next();
```

Answer (score 2):

have a look at the [API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29), particularly the part about `nextLine()`.

Comment: Thank you.  I tried that but it wasn't clearly stating the answer I needed.  You sort of need to know the answer already when looking through the API.

Comment: there is a research element to it.  If you see `nextLine` and you read the text, its kind of obvious.  But i agree with you that it's hard to know where to look sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

`Scanner.next()` only returns the next token, which, by default, is just one word (whitespace-delimited).  If you want the whole sentence you can change the delimiter to '\n': `keyboard.setDelimiter("\n");`, or you can learn loops and then loop over the whole sentence.

Edit: 
Or, as others have pointed out, `nextLine()`.  That's more portable because macs use '\r', which won´ t be caught with what I said.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Program04{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Write a complete sentence with proper grammer:");
        String sentence = keyboard.nextline(); 
        
        *//this graps full text but next ignores the other words after a space is given*
        boolean qMark = sentence.contains("?");
        boolean wow = sentence.contains("!");

        if (qMark)
            System.out.println("Yes");
        else if (wow)
            System.out.println("Wow");
        else
            System.out.println("You always say that.");
    }
}
```